# Delete credit memo through sql

Tags: magento2

I wanted to delete a wrong credit memo so I deleted the wrong credit memo entry from sales_creditmemo and sales_creditmemo_grid. The listing of grid and credit memo is gone but when I view my order I could see refunded amount and comments about refund and the status of some product can also be seen as refunded .

[image]

So can someone explain what else I have to delete to completely get rid of credit memo information and also what is magento way of deleting a credit memo, does even magento provide a way to delete credit memo?

Comment: The answer your looking for is in the sales_order table you need to make sure columns related to refund are set to null and 0 as for the comment you can remove this in sales_order_status_history

Answer (score 0):

**Create Custom Script Like This :-**

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory

 $orderId = '1234546';

$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);

$_creditmemos = $this->Order()->getCreditmemosCollection();

      if($_creditmemos){
          foreach($_creditmemos as $_creditmemo){
              $_creditmemo->delete();
          }
      }
```

**You Can Download Module For Delete Credit Memo :-**

[delete credit memo](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-delete-order-extension.html)

Comment: @rathod thanks for the script , i deleted it through mysql by i guess this will be a much better way , will it also revert the status of refunded from the products whose status changes by creating credit memo ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was looking for the full process to remove a Credit Memo via SQL.

**First remove the credit memo records:**

```
delete from sales_creditmemo where increment_id = <CREDITMEMO_INCREMENT_ID>;
delete from sales_creditmemo_grid where increment_id = <CREDITMEMO_INCREMENT_ID>;
```

**Update the order values:**

```
UPDATE sales_order
SET    state = 'complete',
       status = 'complete',
       base_discount_refunded = NULL,
       discount_refunded = NULL,
       discount_tax_compensation_refunded = NULL,
       base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded = NULL,
       base_shipping_tax_refunded = NULL,
       shipping_tax_refunded = NULL,
       shipping_refunded = NULL,
       base_tax_refunded = NULL,
       tax_refunded = NULL,
       base_subtotal_refunded = NULL,
       subtotal_refunded = NULL,
       base_total_offline_refunded = NULL,
       base_total_refunded = NULL,
       total_offline_refunded = NULL,
       total_refunded = NULL,
       base_shipping_refunded = NULL,
       base_total_online_refunded = NULL,
       total_online_refunded = NULL
WHERE  increment_id = <ORDER_INCREMENT_ID>;
```

**Update the order line values:**

```
UPDATE sales_order_item
SET    qty_refunded = 0.0000,
       amount_refunded = 0.0000,
       base_amount_refunded = 0.0000,
       discount_tax_compensation_refunded = NULL,
       base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded = NULL,
       tax_refunded = NULL,
       base_tax_refunded = NULL,
       discount_refunded = NULL,
       base_discount_refunded = NULL
WHERE  order_id = <ORDER_ID> --note this is the value seen in the URL when viewing the order
```

**Remove Order Comment:**

```
--find the comments for the order
select * from sales_order_status_history where parent_id = <ORDER_ID>

--remove the one referencing the credit
delete from sales_order_status_history where parent_id = <ORDER_ID> and entity_id = <COMMENT_ID>
```

Running the above queries with the correct order references left the order look like it did before the Credit Memo was created.